# Jhipster app fails with the error: JavaScript heap out of memory on mvn package command with prod profile enabled

Tags: maven, jhipster

I have run command. As described in Jhipster docs.

> To package the application as a “production” WAR, type:
>
> ./mvnw -Pprod package

I have no problems running my app in dev mod. The wierd thing is i can run command, at which mvnw fails, according to the log,without an errors.

> yarn run webpack:prod

This command runs perfectly without any mistakes for the first time. But after the command complete i can no longer build the project

> yarn run webpack:build

Returns an error:

```
Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 32-bit with Node.js 6.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.
    at module.exports (D:\Projects\devizion_mock\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\devizion_mock\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
```

I don`t know if this is an  expected behavior. But the only thing that solves this is entirely deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling the dependencies. Only then i can build the project successfully again.

This time i really have no idea where to look or even what to ask from google. I would be greatful for any clues0

This is, i believe, the maven plugin that fails:

```
                             <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                                        <goal>yarn</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore/>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
```

The stack trace of mvnw package -Prod  command error

```
[INFO] $ node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 3.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:48 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-03T15:38:24+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/51M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:yarn (webpack build prod) on project devizion: Failed to run task: 'yarn run webpack:prod' failed. org.ap
ache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:yarn (webpack build prod) on project devizion: Failed to
run task
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:122)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:50)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run task
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException: 'yarn run webpack:prod' failed.
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.YarnTaskExecutor.execute(YarnTaskExecutor.java:64)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.YarnMojo.execute(YarnMojo.java:65)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:115)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutionException: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:82)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput(ProcessExecutor.java:64)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.YarnExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput(YarnExecutor.java:28)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.YarnTaskExecutor.execute(YarnTaskExecutor.java:58)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:74)
        ... 34 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**Edit**

The error that appears after yarn run webpack:prod can be solved with npm rebuild node-sass --force. I tried this before but it did not work. I have had to update my python and .NET SDK for it to work. It still emits some error but nonetheless the projects builds successfully after this command.

Comment: As you're the first one to report such an issue and it seems your project uses node-sass, have you tried commenting out sass plugin in webpack config? Have you tried to increase node memory using `--max-old-space-size` in package.json scripts?

Answer (score 1):

I changed "**max_old_space_size=4096**" for webpack-dev-server and webpack lines to a lower value (2000 in this case) in **package.json** and the issue went away.